# undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sou iniciante em ruby, e tive este erro...

```
 def new
    @section = Section.new({:page_id => @page.id, :name => "Default"})
    @pages = @page.subject.pages.sorted
    @section_count = Section.count + 1
  end
```

Diz que o problema e na linha dois, Alguem me consegue ajudar?

Comment: Pelo visto, `@page` está não inicializado. Bota um `puts @page ` logo no começo do método

Comment: continua a dar o mesmo erro

Comment: Claro que vai dar o mesmo erro. Estou interessado em depurar para saber qual o valor de `@page`. Ele não imprimiu nada? Como você está testando seu código?

Comment: nao imprimiu nada, eu estou a tentar aceder a pagina sections/new apartir do browser

Comment: Você inicia a aplicação a partir de um terminal?

Comment: sim, mas tambem nao imprime nada no terminal

Comment: De onde você desejaria que visse a informação em `@page`? Quem preenche essa informação para você buscar o `id` dela?

Comment: Se possível também, tem como por mais detalhes da classe criada por você?

Comment: Ok, confirmei aqui lendo diversos exemplos. Quando você chama o `new`, seu objeto ainda está vazio. Portanto, `@page` tem valor `nil`. Você precisa passar como argumento de `new` algo para que ele possa iniciar `@page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso está com uma cara danada de ser um método `new` em um controlador de uma aplicação Rails onde `@page` estaria sendo inicializada em algum lugar **fora** do método, provavelmente em um `before_action`. Se você não inicializar `@page` com alguma coisa, ela é automaticamente inicializada com `nil` e vai dar esse erro aí. Procure no seu controlador onde que tem alguma referência de `@page` que você vai encontrar (ou não, se não estiver lá) o seu problema.

Comment: Isso mesmo, se acontecer de o erro continuar, crie um if @page.present? antes de chamá-lo, porque o que acontece é que @page é um objeto, e ele está tentando chamar um atributo de um objeto que não existe, isso gera uma excessão...